# requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

Tags: qt, camera

I tried this example from one of the qml camera tutorials.

The camera is being detected through "cheese", but is not shown through this code.

This code results in "defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

Am using Qt 5.4 with QtGstreamer 1.2

What should I look into?

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.4

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Camera {
        id: camera

        imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

        exposure {
            exposureCompensation: -1.0
            exposureMode: Camera.ExposurePortrait
        }

        flash.mode: Camera.FlashRedEyeReduction

        imageCapture {
            onImageCaptured: {
                photoPreview.source = preview  // Show the preview in an Image
            }
        }
    }

    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
    }

    Image {
        id: photoPreview
    }
}
```

Comment: `no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"` looks like a QtGstreamer camera plugin was not found. Maybe launch with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` env var and look whether the plugin shows up.